# How do I loop through a payload parameter in a GET Request?

Tags: python, request

My goal is to iterate through a list of zip codes to parse data from a website. Instead of enter all of these parameters; I would like to iterate through the list of zip codes

```
import requests 
# List of Zip Codes to Iterate through
zip_codes = ['00001', '10000', '20000', '30000', '40000', '50000', '60000', '70000', '80000', '90000']

# Need to make a loop of all the Zip Codes
payload = {
    'address': zip_codes,
    'radius': 250,
    'pagesize': 40,
    'page': 1,
}

response = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: `responses = (requests.get(url, {**payload, 'address': code}, headers=headers) for code in zip_codes)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for zip_code in zip_codes:
    payload = {
        'address': zip_code,
        ....
    }
    response = requests.get(...)
```

Comment: Wow I did not realize it was that simple.